# How to center an SVG element based on another element using js?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I made an SVG face and want to center each pupil in their respective eye.

I tried doing this by getting the center of the eye using `getBoundingClientRect()`. However when I set the position of the pupil this way it didn't work as expected (it did not center, and changes location based on size of page).

- I'm guessing `getBoundingClientRect()` is related to a global position and the `cx`, `cy` attributes are local, but it's not clear to me what the attributes are local to or how I would fix it

Any ideas why this doesn't work and what approach might fix it?

## Code

```js
// Center the pupil in the eye. Side param is "left" or "right"  
function center_pupil(side) {
    let eye = document.querySelector(`#${side}-eye`).getBoundingClientRect()
    let pupil = document.querySelector(`#${side}-pupil`)
    let pupil_radius = pupil.getAttribute("r")

    pupil.setAttribute("cx", eye.left + eye.width / 2 - pupil_radius)
    pupil.setAttribute("cy", eye.top + eye.height / 2 - pupil_radius)
}

center_pupil("left")
center_pupil("right")
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 645.72 579.45">
            <defs>
                <clipPath id="clip-path" transform="translate(-114.91 -242.55)">
                    <path d="M544,377s9-21,54-25c0,0,114-7,150,25s-43,86-43,86-33.77,18.6-79.06,11.62C615.11,473,587.67,468.87,563,448c-10.53-8.91-25.76-21.79-27-42C535.2,393.05,540.49,382.61,544,377Z"
                        fill="none" />
                </clipPath>
                <clipPath id="clip-path-2" transform="translate(-114.91 -242.55)">
                    <path d="M117.5,397.5a38.69,38.69,0,0,1,8-11c6.89-6.57,14.55-8.78,19-10,32.47-8.93,45-10,45-10,34.68-2.95,53.54-4.56,81-1,33.83,4.38,50.79,6.54,61,21,13.58,19.24,5,45.13,4,48-6.94,20.08-23.19,30.46-35,38a106,106,0,0,1-29.07,12.82,108,108,0,0,1-39.93,3.18c-4.63.72-54.1,7.55-88.32-28.91C120.39,435.31,117.91,406.25,117.5,397.5Z"
                        fill="none" />
                </clipPath>
            </defs>
            <title>face</title>
            <g id="eyes">
                <g id="right-eye">
                    <path d="M540.89,375.37A28.23,28.23,0,0,1,548.4,367a24,24,0,0,1,2.19-1.6c.76-.5,1.5-1,2.26-1.48,1.56-.86,3.07-1.81,4.67-2.55s3.14-1.57,4.76-2.23c.8-.34,1.6-.69,2.39-1.06l2.42-.94c.81-.31,1.61-.65,2.42-1s1.64-.56,2.46-.85l2.46-.81a25.18,25.18,0,0,1,2.49-.73c1.68-.43,3.34-.91,5-1.36s3.38-.71,5.07-1.07l2.54-.55,2.56-.41,5.14-.82c1.81-.26,3.45-.36,5.17-.53l5.12-.43q5.12-.4,10.23-.65a289.41,289.41,0,0,1,41,.71c6.82.65,13.62,1.57,20.39,2.63s13.51,2.37,20.23,3.71,13.41,2.9,20.15,4.54c1.69.38,3.36.86,5,1.36l2.51.73c.83.26,1.65.58,2.48.87l2.47.9c.82.3,1.61.71,2.42,1.05a49,49,0,0,1,4.78,2.33,52.84,52.84,0,0,1,4.63,2.72l2.26,1.48c.75.49,1.44,1.12,2.16,1.68l2.12,1.72c.67.65,1.37,1.27,2,2a30,30,0,0,1,3.57,4.42c.57.78,1,1.65,1.5,2.47s.88,1.73,1.21,2.64a25.41,25.41,0,0,1,1.57,5.59,29.78,29.78,0,0,1-.37,11.31c-4.58,14.09-13,25.18-22.33,35.35a178.89,178.89,0,0,1-14.84,14.31q-3.88,3.39-8,6.53c-2.72,2.11-5.44,4.15-8.32,6.15l-.11.08-.1.05c-2.33,1.23-4.54,2.18-6.86,3.13s-4.62,1.77-7,2.58c-4.68,1.57-9.43,2.87-14.23,4a151.83,151.83,0,0,1-29.28,3.67c-2.46,0-4.93.12-7.39.07l-7.41-.31-7.38-.71c-2.46-.23-4.85-.58-7.3-.93a131.55,131.55,0,0,1-28.88-7.35,114.07,114.07,0,0,1-13.69-6.28c-2.25-1.13-4.38-2.49-6.55-3.78-1.08-.65-2.09-1.41-3.14-2.11s-2.12-1.4-3.1-2.19a143.74,143.74,0,0,1-11.34-9.74,83.58,83.58,0,0,1-10.05-11.51A57.13,57.13,0,0,1,535.46,420a53.51,53.51,0,0,1-2.89-15.38,48.4,48.4,0,0,1,2-15.44,50,50,0,0,1,2.7-7.28c.54-1.17,1.12-2.32,1.76-3.44.31-.56.64-1.11,1-1.65S540.59,375.83,540.89,375.37Zm6.22,3.26c-.75,1.3-1.25,2.21-1.77,3.23s-1,2-1.52,3a56.3,56.3,0,0,0-2.49,6.29,41.51,41.51,0,0,0-2,13.2,34.3,34.3,0,0,0,2.84,12.95,45.72,45.72,0,0,0,7.15,11.32,91.37,91.37,0,0,0,9.77,9.7c3.46,3.07,7.29,6.18,10.83,9a112.56,112.56,0,0,0,23.73,14.54,121.21,121.21,0,0,0,13.15,5,135,135,0,0,0,13.72,3.63c2.31.47,4.7,1,7,1.32s4.69.73,7,1l7.1.56c2.37.13,4.75.12,7.13.18a128.42,128.42,0,0,0,28.29-3.39,135,135,0,0,0,13.69-4c2.23-.81,4.46-1.64,6.63-2.57s4.39-1.91,6.33-3l-.21.13c5.43-3.8,10.71-8.06,15.86-12.34s10.1-8.85,14.78-13.63a103.24,103.24,0,0,0,12.64-15.43,47.41,47.41,0,0,0,4.69-8.65,40.34,40.34,0,0,0,2.28-9.25,33.29,33.29,0,0,0,.35-4.54,22.19,22.19,0,0,0-.46-4.4,20.11,20.11,0,0,0-1.34-4.15c-.25-.67-.64-1.3-1-1.95s-.74-1.27-1.2-1.86a29.21,29.21,0,0,0-6.38-6.48c-.62-.47-1.2-1-1.86-1.44l-2-1.34a46,46,0,0,0-4.12-2.49c-11.39-6-24.05-11.23-37.37-13.24-13.25-2.37-26.77-3-40.22-3.48s-26.92-1-40.43-1.38l-10.13-.24-5.07-.07c-1.66,0-3.42,0-5,0a108.23,108.23,0,0,0-19.78,2.72,24.43,24.43,0,0,0-2.41.65l-2.39.72a43.68,43.68,0,0,0-4.71,1.63c-.77.32-1.55.6-2.3.94s-1.48.75-2.21,1.14-1.47.74-2.17,1.18l-2.06,1.35-1,.68c-.33.24-.64.51-1,.76l-1.9,1.53c-.6.54-1.18,1.11-1.76,1.65a20.72,20.72,0,0,0-1.67,1.71c-.54.58-1.07,1.17-1.54,1.78a21.79,21.79,0,0,0-1.41,1.83l-.66.93-.59.93c-.21.31-.34.62-.52.93-.09.15-.15.29-.22.43Z"
                        transform="translate(-114.91 -242.55)" />
                </g>
                <path d="M505,327" transform="translate(-114.91 -242.55)" />
                <g id="left-eye">
                    <path d="M114.91,397a8.77,8.77,0,0,1,.41-1.29c.07-.21.14-.43.22-.65.15-.43.33-.85.52-1.27a23.67,23.67,0,0,1,1.3-2.43,33.63,33.63,0,0,1,3.35-4.38,39.68,39.68,0,0,1,8.37-7.14,45.38,45.38,0,0,1,9.88-4.59c3.45-1.11,6.75-1.8,10-2.64,6.64-1.59,13.29-3.11,20-4.49,3.35-.68,6.71-1.32,10.08-1.9,1.69-.29,3.38-.58,5.08-.84l2.56-.36,1.29-.16.66-.08.33,0,.17,0,.34,0h-.15l10-.79c3.36-.27,6.71-.48,10.05-1s6.66-1.26,10-1.68,6.74-.55,10.13-.72c6.78-.27,13.6-.4,20.41-.06s13.6.93,20.33,1.86,13.33,1.84,20,2.91a156,156,0,0,1,20.08,4.29c.83.26,1.66.55,2.49.83s1.65.56,2.47.91l2.45,1,2.4,1.19a37.88,37.88,0,0,1,8.79,6.29,39.43,39.43,0,0,1,6.43,8.62,19,19,0,0,1,1.21,2.38l1.11,2.43.86,2.52a18.46,18.46,0,0,1,.77,2.53,57.7,57.7,0,0,1,1.39,20.78,77.82,77.82,0,0,1-1.71,10.2c-.41,1.68-.84,3.35-1.38,5s-1.2,3.27-1.82,4.9a80.14,80.14,0,0,1-10.73,18l-.83,1-.87,1c-.6.64-1.17,1.32-1.79,1.94-1.24,1.23-2.49,2.46-3.82,3.59a93.34,93.34,0,0,1-8.31,6.24c-1.42.95-2.85,1.9-4.28,2.81s-2.82,1.81-4.32,2.74q-4.45,2.71-9.14,5a111.57,111.57,0,0,1-19.45,7.27,109.85,109.85,0,0,1-41.18,3l.81,0a96.63,96.63,0,0,1-10.64.84c-3.53.09-7.06,0-10.58-.18a118,118,0,0,1-20.88-3.16A104.42,104.42,0,0,1,170,482a97.9,97.9,0,0,1-18-11.15,94.11,94.11,0,0,1-26.21-32.74,104.55,104.55,0,0,1-7.36-19.73q-1.36-5.09-2.24-10.3c-.28-1.74-.57-3.48-.77-5.23-.12-.87-.2-1.75-.29-2.63l-.07-.66-.07-.86C114.94,398.15,114.92,397.55,114.91,397Zm5.18,1.08a7,7,0,0,1,.08.79l0,1.06c.05.83.09,1.67.17,2.5.11,1.68.31,3.34.51,5,.46,3.33,1.1,6.63,1.88,9.91.39,1.63.86,3.25,1.32,4.86s1,3.21,1.62,4.78c1.17,3.15,2.48,6.25,4,9.27a87.88,87.88,0,0,0,42.45,41.16,99.57,99.57,0,0,0,19,6.34,112.17,112.17,0,0,0,19.92,2.62c3.35.14,6.71.15,10.05,0a89,89,0,0,0,9.9-.94l.38-.06.43,0a105.31,105.31,0,0,0,19.53.1A110.47,110.47,0,0,0,270.55,482a104.55,104.55,0,0,0,18.21-6.92,96.58,96.58,0,0,0,8.52-4.71c1.36-.84,2.79-1.77,4.18-2.67s2.76-1.83,4.12-2.75c2.72-1.85,5.3-3.82,7.85-5.8s5-4,7.4-6.21a51.27,51.27,0,0,0,6.53-7.12,42.86,42.86,0,0,0,4.84-8.38,61.67,61.67,0,0,0,4.57-18.91,52.32,52.32,0,0,0-1.7-19.18,18.18,18.18,0,0,0-.76-2.26l-.84-2.22-1.06-2.12a16.05,16.05,0,0,0-1.13-2.08,35,35,0,0,0-5.82-7.29,34.22,34.22,0,0,0-7.68-5.19l-2.14-1-2.23-.86c-.73-.3-1.5-.55-2.27-.78s-1.53-.49-2.31-.71a160.49,160.49,0,0,0-19.39-3.74c-6.59-.93-13.26-1.73-19.92-2.52a264.5,264.5,0,0,0-39.7-1.74c-3.33.07-6.65.33-10,.27s-6.72-.28-10.08-.29a96.26,96.26,0,0,0-10.05.57l-10,.9h-.16l-2.26.33-2.48.41c-1.65.29-3.3.61-4.95.95-3.3.7-6.59,1.48-9.87,2.28-6.56,1.62-13.08,3.42-19.58,5.32-3.23,1-6.56,1.86-9.53,3a39,39,0,0,0-8.42,4.28,34.43,34.43,0,0,0-6.92,6.22,46.51,46.51,0,0,0-2.8,3.73l-1.37,1.92-.7,1-.37.48A.39.39,0,0,0,120.09,398Z"
                        transform="translate(-114.91 -242.55)" />
                </g>
            </g>
            <g clip-path="url(#clip-path)">
                <circle id="right-pupil" cx="532.09" cy="125.45" r="31" />
            </g>
            <g clip-path="url(#clip-path-2)">
                <circle id="left-pupil" cx="116.59" cy="139.95" r="31" />
            </g>
            <g id="Layer_4" data-name="Layer 4">
                <path d="M505,264s120-29,194-10" transform="translate(-114.91 -242.55)" fill="none" stroke="#000"
                    stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="10" />
                <path d="M154,280s116-27,179,0" transform="translate(-114.91 -242.55)" fill="none" stroke="#000"
                    stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="10" />
                <path d="M390,401c9.15,143.49,6.63,190.63,2,205,0,0-6.53,20.28-2,41a35.35,35.35,0,0,0,4,10s1.3,2.14,8,10"
                    transform="translate(-114.91 -242.55)" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-miterlimit="10"
                    stroke-width="10" />
                <line x1="321.09" y1="415.45" x2="329.09" y2="424.45" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-miterlimit="10"
                    stroke-width="10" />
                <path d="M363,774l146-4s-1,47-73,47S363,774,363,774Z" transform="translate(-114.91 -242.55)" fill="none"
                    stroke="#000" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="10" />
            </g>
        </svg>
```

## What I'm currently seeing

Note: pupil location changes based on screen size

[image]